# Is it possible to have a "no-op" IAM policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

What I have in mind in something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": []
}
```

But the policy editor rejects it for not containing any statements. I obviously understand why AWS enforces the condition that there must be a statement, so I'm more interested in answers explaining if/how to achieve a no-op statement than in answers explaining AWS's rationale here or asking why I want to do this.

Comment: Whats the use case? By default having no policy is implicitely denying everything :)

Comment: No use case. Just curious. Users can still access any resources with resource policies that grant them permission, even with the implicit deny.

Comment: I would guess its by design to reduce the need to evaluate against a blank statement.

Comment: DO you really want a no-op, or would an innocuous request like `iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy` suffice?

Comment: @JamesShapiro — your comment where you say "*even with the implicit deny*" seems to suggest that you're trying to somehow "disable" an implicit deny? Really, without more clarity on what exactly you want to achieve, the only answer is: there's no "no-op" policy. So, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: BrunoReis you're reading too much into my comment, I don't mean to disable anything. @Parsifal, an innocuous request would suffice. If you add that as an answer I will vote it up. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that it would be useful for other people without the context of _why_ it's useful to do this. If it gives you the answer that you need, I'm glad to have helped.

Comment: I have an immediate use case for this: constructing policies dynamically in Terraform that may end up containing nothing. For now my solution is a complex set of for_each expressions to conditionally exclude the policies involved that I'd much more happily avoid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to create the following, I use in Terraform as a dummy policy when none is needed. Seems to work as long as AWS doesn't create an action of `none:null`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "none:null",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can also use an action like `none:NoSuchActionExistsFoobar` which is very unlikely to be created by Amazon.  Tested something like this